# How to install libssl-dev on Slackware?

Tags: software-installation, slackware

libssl-dev does not seem to be installed on my Slackware server and is needed for various dependencies. How can I install this on Slackware? Searching around did not find anything and there really isn't a package manager with Slackware. I did try slackpkg, but there are no libssl packages on there.

I do already have `openssl` installed and have for a long time. Is this a separate package from OpenSSL?